# ExtJS Change actioncolumn icon from controller / handler

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**TLDR**: I'm using ExtJS 4 and I want to change action column buttons icon from `hanlder` / controller. How I can do it?

**My problem**: I have a menu to create a group of devices, it cointain a table of all existing devices (the device has an `id`, `name` and affiliation to the group `member`) with pagination and ajax store. To create a group I have to pass an array of device ids to the server.

To do this I add action column to my grid. By clicking on button in action column I want to add device id to one of the two arrays, that are stored as attributes of the grid (`addedMembers` and `deletedMembers`) and change icon in action column. At the moment, all the following code works, but I do not understand how I can change the icon?

Grid:

```
Ext.define('Portal.view.devicegroups.GroupDevicesGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.groupDevicesGrid',

addedMembers: [],
deletedMembers: [],

store: 'devicegroups.GroupDevicesStore',

columns: [
    {
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        text: Ext.String.capitalize("<?=gettext('name')?>")
    },
    {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        text: Ext.String.capitalize("<?=gettext('member')?>"),
        width: 75,
        items: [
            {
                getClass: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var cls = 'deny';
                    if (this.up('groupDevicesGrid').deletedMembers.indexOf(record.get('id')) !== -1 || record.get('member') == 1) {
                        cls = 'allow';
                    }
                    return cls;
                },
                handler: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
                    this.fireEvent('changeMembership', rowIndex, record);
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
```

`changeMembership` method:

```
    changeGroupDeviceMembership: function(rowIndex, device) {
    var groupDevicesGrid = this.getGroupDevicesGrid(),
        groupDevicesStore = groupDevicesGrid.getStore(),
        addedMembers = groupDevicesGrid.addedMembers,
        deletedMembers = groupDevicesGrid.deletedMembers,
        deviceId = device.get('id'),
        isMember = device.get('member');
    if(isMember == 1) {
        if(deviceId) {
            if(deletedMembers.indexOf(deviceId) === -1) {
                // Set allow icon
                deletedMembers.push(deviceId);
            } else {
                // Set deny icon
                deletedMembers.splice(deletedMembers.indexOf(deviceId), 1);
            }
        }
    } else if(isMember == 0) {
        if(deviceId) {
            if(addedMembers.indexOf(deviceId) === -1) {
                // Set deny icon
                addedMembers.push(deviceId);
            } else {
                // Set allow icon
                addedMembers.splice(deletedMembers.indexOf(deviceId), 1);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Or perhaps there is a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3):

I am not privileged to comment so I will just take a shot at the answer. This is the way I do it..you are nearly there just add iconCls. :)

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    text: Ext.String.capitalize("<?=gettext('member')?>"),
    width: 75,
    items: [
        {
            iconCls:'deny', //<== try adding this icon cls
            getClass: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var cls = 'deny';
                meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="Deny"'; //<== I like tool tips
                if (this.up('groupDevicesGrid').deletedMembers.indexOf(record.get('id')) !== -1 || record.get('member') == 1) {
                    cls = 'allow';
                    meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="Allow"'; //<== I like tool tips
                }
                return cls;
            },
            handler: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
                this.fireEvent('changeMembership', rowIndex, record);
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I use this pattern quite a lot, hopefully it works for you too.